# how to redirect external HTML to wordpress if wp user is logged in ?

Tags: php, wordpress

title pretty much explains it. I have an index.php page (**OUTSIDE**) of Wordpress. This index page has a login from that redirects to Wordpress logged in area once submitted.

The problem is if I go back to the external index.php after login I'll still see the login form , which is not right, what php can I use to redirect back to Wordpress members area ONLY if logged in of course.

Comment: Could be anything. Hard to tell without the related code in question.

Comment: what do u need ? it's only a login form in HTML on my index page ... and it does work without any php to login my users and takes them to wordrpess... I tired this and didn't work ... <?php 
require('./access/wp-load.php');
?>
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
 wp_redirect ('./access/' );
 exit;
 }
?>

Comment: I need an answer guys , come on !

Comment: Since you apparently have a subdirectory instalation... have you checked the cookie path ?

Comment: can u elaborate ?

Comment: no haven't touched anything with cookies , can u tell me what need to be done there ?

Comment: Check the developer tools on your browser, Storage tab. If the path on the cookie is set to /access/ (your wp install), it cannot be read from /

Comment: I checked there, and it seems to be set to /access/ ... so now how can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) have a set of security features and given the subdirectory installation this seems the most relevant:

> Path indicates a URL path that must exist in the requested URL in
>   order to send the Cookie header.

Since you are trying to authenticate the user from the domain root, the browser never sends the cookie because it's not allowed. Change the constant `COOKIEPATH` to '/' in [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Additional_Defined_Constants).

For completeness, once the cookies are set up and Wordpress bootstraped (by requiring `wp-load`:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
  wp_redirect (admin_url());
  exit;
}
```

[`admin_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/) is a helper function that:

> Retrieves the URL to the **admin area** for the current site.

If you want to redirect to a public page instead, you can use [`site_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/):

> Retrieves the URL for the current site where WordPress application files.

Comment: great , but what needs to be edited in wp-config ? please let me know if u can help .. I get ur concept , but I don't know what to do here !!

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý I edited the answer 7 hours ago, did you try and didn't work ?

Comment: oh , sorry didn't see that ... BUT I don't actually see somehing called cookiepath in the CONFIG file ..  
what line are u refering too in CONFIG ??

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý I linked the configuration reference where states "Here are additional constants that **can** be defined" . There's even an example.

Comment: I added  this AT THE END OF THE WP-CONFIG file : define( 'COOKIEPATH', preg_replace( '|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option( 'home' ) . '/' ) );.. and then this on the top my index page: <?php 
    if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect ( home_url("./access") );
        exit;
    }
?> 

.. Index still shows blank white page ?

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý That's the default value. Use define('COOKIEPATH', '/'); And be sure to clear existing cookies (check the console again to verify is applying the new configuration)

Comment: so the cookie path is all set good now ... but I still have the problem ,,, what code should I be using on my EXTERNAL INDEX.PHP to redirect back to wordrpess if logged in , and do I need to start a session or something ? what to do here , what code ?

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý you had that part in your first comment, just remove the dot in the `wp_redirect()` call

Comment: u mean ,  wp_redirect ('/access/' ); exit; } ?> ??

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý Yes, but you **really** should check for updated answers. That version doesn't have hardcoded paths (and you mention you want to redirect directly to members area)

Comment: exactly man , Idk why this is taking for ever .... the login form is basically all HTML has no php or anything related to wordpress @ all .. would u please guide me on what to do here !!! I need this badly.

Comment: if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
  wp_redirect (admin_url());
  exit;
} ... WHAT IS THAT , ADMIN URL ? and this goes all the way on top on my page ? u mean ? and what If I want it to redirect to another custom page ? ALSO WHEN I REQUIRE WP-LOAD ,, it changed the whole style of my EXTERNAL INDEX PAGE , nothing more

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý I'm sorry but I'm afraid not, there's not much to go on here... But I can tell you that the code works, and wp-load really shouldn't alter your styles at all so maybe check your server logs and generated html ?

Comment: THANX FOR ALL UR HELP AND PATIENCE ,, FINALLY THE REDIRECT NOW WORKS ... The only thing now is that placing that code on my external index page , it takes away the style from the home page making it all white lol , WHY ? any thoughts ?

Comment: DOOONE ,,, ALL DONE , I added define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); and now everything working perfect ... thanx a million again mate

Comment: @MøhamëdNagý I could swear this shouldn't happen. Just curiosity at this point, are you including any other wordpress file by chance ?